# Skype for Business Service Health for Multiple Devices

Tags: powershell, skype, skype-for-business

I've been working at this script for a while and I can't seem to figure it out:

```
$servers = Get-Content -path c:\users\jason\documents\skyperservers.txt
Foreach ($server in $servers){get-cswindowservice -computername $servers | where-object {$_.status -eq "running"}}
```

I keep getting the error

> Get-CSWindowService : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
> 'System.String' required by parameter 'ComputerName'. Specified method
> is not supported...

Essentially, I'm trying to display all services from the command for each skype server and their service health status whether "running" or "stopped"

Answer (score 0):

Two things about your code:

1. You are iterating the **collection** `$servers` using variable `$server`, but you do not use that as parameter for the Get-CSWindowService cmdlet. Instead you feed it the entire collection $server**s** (`System.Object[]`), which is what the error is telling you.
2. If you also want to see servers where the CsWindowService is stopped, add this to your Where-Object clause and best return **objects** so you can combine the service status with the server name.

Try

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path 'c:\users\jason\documents\skyperservers.txt'
$result = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Get-CsWindowService -ComputerName $server | 
    # or use regex:  Where-Object {$_.Status -match 'Running|Stopped'}
    Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running' -or $_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} |
    # include the server name in the output
    Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$server}}, Status
}
```

Now you can display the results on screen

```
$result
```

or for instance save the results to a Csv file

```
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\SkypeServers_Status.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply! Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error with your suggested script.

Comment: @alfalfa14 Then check your skypeservers.txt file. It should be a text file where each server name is on a separate line. If this is not the case, please add a sample of the file to your question.

Comment: @alfalfa14 Did you check your skyperservers.txt file? You never responded and did not show an example of that file. As my code is iterating the collection`$servers` (plural) and inside the loop uses `$server` (singular), it is impossible it generates an eror like _Get-CSWindowService : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ComputerName'._